# Sparx EA - Is there a way to include Diagram Filters in published HTML Reports

Tags: enterprise-architect

Sparx EA - Is there a way to include Diagram Filters in published HTML Reports. Would like to have the flexibility to filter diagrams published in HTML reports, based on certain tags.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

Not my expertise, but AFAIK you can't. You could probably write some JavaScript stuff or if you limit it to predefined filtering use some style sheet. But the diagrams are rendered as png when EA exports them. So everything is fixed. The ability to apply a filter would mean the browser has to know what's in the png.